# How to return non static variable from static method ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, class, static, ecmascript-6, export

I have following code:

```
export class Utils{
    constructor() {
        this.dateFormat = "MM-DD-YY";
    }

    static getFormat() {
        return this.dateFormat;
    }
}
```

when I am trying to import this class to other file and try to call the static method `gteFormat` it return `undefined`.
Here is how I am doing it:

```
import * as Utils from "./commons/Utils.js";

class ABC {
    init(){
        console.log(Utils.Utils.getFormat());// gives undefined
    }
}
```

How can I make this static method return the `dateFormat` property?

Comment: `this` refers to a specific object in the class. A static method is not associated with any object, so what do you expect `this.dateFormat` to return?

Comment: If you want to have a default `dateFormat`, declare it as a variable in the class, not a property of an object.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks, right now all I can think of doing this is: `Utils.dateFormat='myformat'`. Is this the correct way or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: If the only thing on your class is static methods, you don't need a class at all, just export the function.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: I have multiple static methods which may use some common constants. I am not sure how would I make those methods. I don't want to put those constants in some other file as they are needed only here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are conceptually working with a bunch of functions, you can consider relying on the module scope itself for privacy, rather than the class structure. Then you can export functions or values directly. Like

```
const dateFormat = "MM-DD-YY";

export function getFormat() {
    return dateFormat;
}
```

with usage like

```
import * as Utils from "./commons/Utils.js";

console.log(Utils.getFormat())
```

or even

```
import { getFormat } from "./commons/Utils.js";

console.log(getFormat())
```

or if it's literally a constant you can export it directly

```
export const DATE_FORMAT = "MM-DD-YY";
```

then

```
import { DATE_FORMAT } from "./commons/Utils.js";
console.log(DATE_FORMAT);
```

Exporting a class with a bunch of static methods is a very Java-y way to write it, and the class itself adds nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have to go this way. I wish there was some other way where I can use classes just to keep things consistent.

Comment: I'd really recommend against thinking of it that way. Javascript is a function-based language, classes are sugar on top, not the other way around. Using classes for everything makes things needlessly complex.

Answer (score 0):

### Constructors are for instances

Think about it: a `constructor` is called when an instance is created, setting static defaults is probably better done elsewhere, for example when declaring the static variable

```js
class Utils {

    static dateFormat = "MM-DD-YY";
    
    static getFormat() {
        return this.dateFormat;
    }
}

console.log(Utils.getFormat())
```

If, for some reason, you have to set this in a `constructor` anyways, the correct syntax will be `Utils.dateFormat = "..."`. Funny side fact is that you can use `this` when reading (in the `return` statement). However, you would still have to instanciate an instance of `Utils` in order for `dateFormat` to be sth. other than `undefined`:

```js
class Utils {

    static dateFormat;
    
    constructor() {
       Utils.dateFormat = "MM-DD-YY"; // use Utils.dateFormat when writing
    }
    
    static getFormat() {
        return this.dateFormat; // use whatever you like when reading... :/
    }
}

console.log(`Before instanciating: ${Utils.getFormat()}`);

var dummy = new Utils();

console.log(`After instanciating: ${Utils.getFormat()}`);
```

### A sidenote on your `import` statement

you could avoid having to call `Utils.Utils.getFormat()` everytime, which looks a bit weird, by refactoring your `import`-statement like so:

```
// import * as Utils from "./commons/Utils.js";
import { Utils } from "./commons/Utils.js";

class ABC {
    init(){
        //console.log(Utils.Utils.getFormat());
        console.log(Utils.getFormat());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wonder if  while calling the constructor is the purpose of having `static` is being served or not.

Comment: I don't think so, i just wanted to point out that it is possible to do so ;)

Comment: also have a look at @loganfsmyth's answer, which points out some good approaches to your actual problem